# How to detect whether Python variable is an import from future

Tags: python

How can we detect if a Python variable is an import from `__future__`?

I've noticed it's a class, specifically, `__future__._Feature()`. However, all attempts at importing that class seem to fail.

`type()` returns `<class '__future__._Feature'>`

My attempts at getting the `_Feature` class:

```
>>> from __future__ import absolute_import

>>> absolute_import
_Feature((2, 5, 0, 'alpha', 1), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 16384)

>>> type(abolute_import)
<class '__future__._Feature'>

>>> from __future__ import _Feature
SyntaxError: future feature _Feature is not defined

>>> import __future__._Feature
ImportError: No module named '__future__._Feature'; '__future__' is not a package

>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do it is to extract the type from a known "_Feature" and use that:

```
from __future__ import division
Feature = type(division)

from __future__ import unicode_literals
isinstance(unicode_literals, Feature)
```

(yields True)

That may look a "hack" - but it is actually the way to retrieve a couple of classes defined in native code that are not available for direct importing. The much more useful `FunctionType` can be imported with `from types import FunctionType` - but if you open the Python file for the `types` module, you will see it is declared as something like: `FunctionType = type(lambda: None)`

That said, I wonder what is the motivation for you to check the type of a `_Feature` of the `__future__` imports - these are mostly placeholders so that it is possible to use the import syntax to enable the features. The changes `__future__` imports cause goes directly into the each compiled code object, as a flag, and changes the behavior of byte code execution itself. 
You can certainly delete these `_Feature` objects from your module, and the feature itself will still be enabled for that module -

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> del division
>>> 5 / 2
2.5
```

Comment: Motivation: It was an attempt to list modules in a package, excluding stdlib (a solved problem) and `__future__` imports.